# Fixed footer and content filler with boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to put the footer at the bottom of the browser window and fill the empty part with the container when necessary(. This is my structure:

```
<header>
    <div class='container'>
        ....
    </div>
</header>
<div id='wrap'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='white-background'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-5 leftcontent'>[%leftcontent%]</div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-7 maincontent'>[%maincontent%]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class='container'>
        <div style='text-align: center; padding-bottom: 20px;'><h3>[%copyright%]</h3></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And this is the css:

```
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image:url('bk.gif');
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.white-background{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color: #fff!important;
}

footer{
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

I have done some tries and took a look to other answers, but without success...

Answer (score 0):

Try add first stycky footer solution

http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/